# Gradle root project with multiple applications

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How do I create a gradle root project with multiple applications that use the same library.  I'm wanting to end up with tar and zip files containing:

```
RootProject/
  bin/
    Command1
    Command2
    ...
  lib/
    Library.jar
    ..
```

I created a gradle root project, the library sub-project, and several application sub-projects:

```
RootProject/
  settings.gradle
  build.gradle
  common.gradle
  Library/
    build.gradle
    src/main/java/Library.java
  Command1/
    build.gradle
    src/main/java/Command1.java
  Command2/
    build.gradle
    src/main/java/Command2.java
```

My current root project's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'base' // To add "clean" task to the root project.

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    group = 'edu.csusb.ecs.gmailsettings'
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    dependencies {
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    }
}

task build(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn subprojects.build
    from subprojects.collect { it.tasks.withType(Jar) }
    into project.rootProject.buildDir.toString() + "/libs"
}

task clean(group:project.rootProject.ext.group, type: Delete, description:"clean jars from subprojects") {
    delete fileTree(project.buildDir).include('**/*')
}
```

results in an error

> org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using
>   Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip'.     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.gradle.model.GenericModelFetcher.getModels(GenericModelFetcher.java:168)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.NbGradle18ModelLoader$ProjectModelFetcher.getModels(NbGradle18ModelLoader.java:379)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.NbGradle18ModelLoader.loadModels(NbGradle18ModelLoader.java:68)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader.loadModelWithProgress(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:559)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader.access$1600(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:64)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader$6.run(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:419)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.runNonBlockingGradleTask(GradleDaemonManager.java:35)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.access$100(GradleDaemonManager.java:22)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$2.execute(GradleDaemonManager.java:125)
>     at
>   org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$FunctionWrapper.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:270)
>     at
>   org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$TaskOfAbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jtrim.concurrent.Tasks$RunOnceCancelableTask.execute(Tasks.java:342)
>     at
>   org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.runTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:919)
>     at
>   org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.access$1200(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:898)
>     at
>   org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.executeTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:815)
>     at
>   org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.processQueue(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:827)
>     at
>   org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$1.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:453)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file
>   '/Users/000017913/Development/GmailSettings/build.gradle' line: 20 A
>   problem occurred evaluating root project 'GmailSettings'.     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:137)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred
>   evaluating root project 'GmailSettings'.  at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:204)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:209)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:667)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:136)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:249)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:167)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
>     ... 62 more Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException:
>   Declaring custom 'build' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle
>   plugins is not allowed.   at
>   org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin$7.execute(LifecycleBasePlugin.java:142)
>     at
>   org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin$7.execute(LifecycleBasePlugin.java:138)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$CompositeSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:196)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.MutableActionSet.execute(MutableActionSet.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:204)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:198)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:93)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.addTask(DefaultTaskContainer.java:101)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:81)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.task(DefaultProject.java:1209)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.metaobject.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:134)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:160)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:83)
>     at
>   build_dycfbq39lcq7wcyu7h089vex6.run(/Users/000017913/Development/GmailSettings/build.gradle:20)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
>     ... 94 more

Comment: You need to a single distribution with all `Command*` inside? Why? How is it suppose to work? Every single `Command*` is a runnable application?

Comment: I'm wanting NetBeans 8.2 (with the Gradle Support plugin) to build a distribution containing a collection of commands.

Answer (score 0):

in my root projects build.gradle I defined a task to copy all subprojects jar files into the `/build/libs` folder of the root project like this:

```
task build(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn subprojects.build
        // from subprojects.collect { it.tasks.withType(AbstractArchiveTask) }
        from subprojects.collect { it.tasks.withType(Jar) }
        into project.rootProject.buildDir.toString() + "/libs"
}

task clean(group:project.rootProject.ext.group, type: Delete, description:"clean jars from subprojects") {
    delete fileTree(project.buildDir).include('**/*')
}
```

you should be able to copy any other build artefacts to the root project in a similar way.

Comment: I'm getting a org.gradle.tooling.BuildException.

Comment: probably your root project has no ext.group property or is no multiproject?

Comment: Your root project has no ext.group You may also eliminate the ext.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help all. The following, derrived from your input seems to work.

```
task copyJars(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn subprojects.build
    from subprojects.collect { it.tasks.withType(Jar) }
    into project.rootProject.buildDir.toString() + "/libs"
}

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from subprojects.collect { it.configurations.runtime }
    into project.rootProject.buildDir.toString() + "/libs"
}

task copyStartScripts(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn copyJars
    from subprojects.collect { it.tasks.withType(CreateStartScripts) }
    into project.rootProject.buildDir.toString() + "/scripts"
}

task createDistribution() {
    apply plugin: 'distribution'

    distributions {
        main {
            contents {
                from(copyStartScripts) {
                    into "bin"
                    fileMode = 0755
                }
                from(copyJars) {
                    into "lib"
                }
                from(copyDependencies) {
                    into "lib"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```